# is there a way to configure a local systemd service to be a "proxy" for a remote service?

Tags: linux, systemd

I am running in an embedded environment where multiple hosts have a cryptographically secure network between each other.

One of my hosts is the so-called "service module" where sysadmins and technicians can login. There are services to be managed on multiple other nodes.

Is there a way to configure systemd on the service module so that the following commands expand out to the respective desired commands in the comment?

```
systemctl restart controller      # => systemctl -h controller restart controller
systemctl restart telemetry       # => systemctl -h communications restart telemetry
systemctl restart any-other-thing # => systemctl restart any-other-thing
```

The clumsy way to do this would be to use bash tricks like aliases, but I'd really like to be able to create a proxy for that `controller` service so that all systemctl command correctly route to the remote host (e.g. `systemctl (start|stop|status|restart)`, or even `journalctl`).